# OSX Server permissions weirdness

Tags: permissions, mac-osx-server

I have a work network running off an OSX server. I've set the permissions so that any user in our group can access a certain folder. It's become apparent though, that whenever a user accesses a folder, that the folder becomes locked for all other users afterwords, and I have to reset the permissions again. No clue why this is happening.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "accesses a folder"?  Do the permissions change just by virtue of looking at it in the Finder? Do you get problems when users create folders?

Comment: I believe it's when a user makes changes or adds folders to the directory. I don't think it's by viewing the directory though. But I haven't tested that yet.

Comment: Probably to do with permission inheritance then. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Server Admin to set ACL permissions on a shared folder? Do you have permission inheritance enabled?

If you're going to change ACLs on an existing directory you should also propagate permissions to ensure everything below the directory has the correct permissions.

EDIT: what you probably want to do is add an ACL group permission for to the folder using Server Admin. Choose a *custom* permission. Edit the permission and check everything *except* `Change Permissions`, `Change Owner`, and `Delete`. The 4 Inheritance permissions are the important ones.

This is how I have a couple of shared folders set up on my server.

Comment: +1 for ACL's.  Standard OS X POSIX permissions are default 755, which doesn't help in a group situation.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, Adobe CS will ignore ACL and SL Server doesn't allow you to set the default POSIX permissions (although 10.4 server and earlier did). So this is both Apple's fault (for taking away the option) and Adobe's fault (for ignoring ACLs).